# debug useCallback with debouncer resets useState variables

Tags: reactjs

All my state variables are resetting back to what the initial page load was every time the debouncer starts. Does anyone have a more workable solution than this?

note: `debounce` is coming from `import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';`

[image]

Every solution I have found on the web recommends:

- `useCallback`, `useMemo`, or `useRef` (all experience the same bug), or...
- is a solution that is wrapped within a class component (I'm not using class components in this project)
- is a hacky solution where the content of my code (much larger than what is shown in those function bodies) would be hard to integrate with.

None of the above seem to be able to squash this bug. I'm open to suggestions or other recommended debouncer plugins for reactjs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

even though the `useState` variables show up as their initial values within the debouncer, it looks like if I use the debounce to just `setState` on a boolean, and have a `useEffect` listener on that state, you can call that function...

```
  const [executeDebouncer, setExecuteDebouncer] = useState(false);
  // const debounceUpdateProductsInOrder = useCallback(debounce(orderUpdater, 3000), []);
  const debounceUpdateProductsInOrder = useCallback(
    debounce(() => setExecuteDebouncer(true), 3000),
    [],
  );
```

add the `useEffect` here...

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (executeDebouncer) {
      setExecuteDebouncer(false);
      orderUpdater();
    }
  }, [executeDebouncer]);
```