# Debounce is not working when i am trying to filter the search results by typing in the input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debouncing

I am trying to filter my search results using debounce lodash. I ma able to filter but the debounce is not working the way it is supposed to. Every time I enter text in the input an API call is made.
I am unable to figure out the problem. Attached please see my Stackbiz link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nqordc?description=A%20create-react-app%20project%20based%20on%20react%20and%20react-dom&file=src%2Fcomponents%2FFilter.js,src%2Fstyle.css,src%2FApp.js&title=React%20Starter

line 47 , I am doing console.log to check the debounce and it doesn't work. Please let me know the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: yes it does work, and 500ms after your last `input` event, it invokes the debounced function. try with 2000ms and you'll see

Comment: Thanks! but why in the console I see each letter as I type ? Is it not supposed to show me letters after I stop typing ?

Comment: you are "debouncing" the fetch part after the last input. other than that the event `input` works as it should and types as you type

Answer (score 0):

First, as IT goldman pointed out, the debounce function is working ok. But there's another problem.

You are creating the debounce function everytime React rerenders. In this case, React will rerender everytime you type a character since it will change the state of the input.

So to fix this, you should create the debounced function by using `useCallback`, since using `useCallback` will prevent the function to be unnecessarily created. I've tried and it seems to work well.

```
const handleSearch = useCallback(
    debounce((searchTerm) => {
      const filteredData = data.filter((item) =>
        item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
      );
      setFilteredData(() => {
        console.log('set data', searchTerm); // this will log everytime we change filteredData
        return filteredData;
      });
    }, 2000),
    [] // add necessary dependencies here
  );
```

I still recommend you to rebuild the app and add necessary dependencies into the `useCallback` since I was only trying to find out what's work.

This is a nice question I was using to complete the code if you're interested.
[Lodash debounce with React Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36294134/lodash-debounce-with-react-input)